# React native with firebase cloud emssaging error:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement notification feature using firebase and react native, but with this code I'm getting this error.

> ERROR  Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

what can I do to fix it.
I don't think FCM will require database url

here are my code.

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer, useIsFocused} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Platform, PermissionsAndroid, Alert} from 'react-native';
import messaging, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';


const App = ()=>{
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
<>//rest code</>
)
}
```

Please provide me sample firebase config needed for this FCM.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for integrating Firebase into a web app?  It involves calling initializeApp with your project configuration, as the error message says. https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: This is not web app, its android or ios react native application.

Comment: please if you know the solution for this let me know

Comment: Did you complete the platform specific instructions for the platform you're using that generated this error?  You should be clear if this is happening on Android or iOS, and what you did to set it up.  Please edit the question to be clear how to reproduce this. https://rnfirebase.io/

Comment: I added firebase config object, but its asking to add database  url, I don't have database url since I'am dealing with FCM

const check = async () => {
    await firebase.initializeApp({
      // Your Firebase configuration object
      apiKey: "d"-,
      projectId: "....",
      messagingSenderId: "....",
      appId: "app-id"
    });
    
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   check()
  }, []);

Comment: Double check all steps of installation! specifically native setup. https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage
https://rnfirebase.io/